# Integration by subsitution of $\int \frac {x^5}{(1+x^2)^3} dx$

Tags: integration

Let $I = \int \frac {x^5}{(1+x^2)^3} dx$

$i) $ Using the substitution $u = 1+x^2$, show that $I = \int \frac {(u-1)^2}{2u^3} du$

$ii)$ Hence find the exact value of $I$.

I got part $i$ but I don't know how to integrate it in part $ii$ any advice please?

Also, I don't know how to put the limits on the integrals, but for the first integral the limits are from 1 to 0 and in the second the limits are from 1 to 2.

Comment: $0 \leq x \leq 1 \implies 1 \leq 1 + x^2 \leq 2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$\frac{(u-1)^2}{2u^3} = \frac{1}{2u} - \frac{1}{u^2} + \frac{1}{2u^3}$$

Comment: Yup, just expand the numerator and split fractions appropriately.

Comment: I integrated this wrt to u and I got this:

$\frac {1}{2} ln(2u) - ln(u^2) + \frac {1}{2}ln(2u^3)$, is this correct? When I substiute for x I get the wrong answer

Comment: Unless $p = -1$, you have $\int_a^b u^p \, du$ is $\frac{1}{p+1} u^{p+1}|_a^b$. If $p = -1$, then $\int_a^b u^p \,du = \ln(u)|_a^b$.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me how to write limits in integrals too please, thank you!

Comment: First: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Integrals,_sums_and_limits
Second: Note that $\int_a^b c u^p \, du = c \int_a^b u^p \,du$, so, e.g., $\int_1^2 \frac{1}{2u}\,du  = \frac{1}{2} \int_1^2 \frac{1}{u}\,du$...

Answer (score 0):

Hint -

$$I = \frac {(u-1)^2}{2u^3} du$$

$$= \frac {u^2+1-2u}{2u^3} du$$

$$= \frac {u^2}{2u^3}du + \frac {1}{2u^3}du - \frac {2u}{2u^3} du$$

Hope you can proceed now.